# Is it possible to list users in a specific orgunit with the google admin sdk directory api?

Tags: google-admin-sdk

Im using the Directory API in the Google admin SDK to manage users in Google domains.
I'm looking for a way to list users in a specific orgunit in the domain but I don't find any examples on how to achieve this.
According to the documentation https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/reference/users/list the only valid query attributes are email, familyName and givenName.
The workaround im using today is to get all users in the domain and then filter the response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your findings are correct, there's no way to retrieve only users in a given OU. You can retrieve just email and OrgUnit using the fields parameter and then filter locally. Using fields should reduce traffic and improve efficiency somewhat.

Comment: This is no longer true. See Gwyn Howell's answer below.

Answer (score 9):

This is possible using the `query` parameter.

Example:

```
/admin/directory/v1/users?domain=domain.com&query=orgUnitPath=/Sales
```

or, url encoded:

```
/admin/directory/v1/users?domain=example.com&query=orgUnitPath%3D%2FSales
```

Will return all users in the `/Sales` orgunit.

Full docs [here](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/guides/search-users).

Comment: How do you combine search clauses in the query? For example, I want to search for all suspended users in an org unit. I tried  query=orgUnitPath=/Sales,isSuspended=true and it didn't work. I replaced the comma with ampersand (&). That didn't work either.

Comment: From the docs https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/guides/search-users "Multiple clauses are separated by whitespace and are implicitly joined by an AND operator."

Answer (score 0):

I used the 'query' parameter as explained in https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/reference/rest/v1/users/list and it works.

```
var optionalArgs = {
        customer: 'my_customer',
        orderBy: 'email',
        query: "orgUnitPath='/A1 - Current Members'"
      };
    
   var response = AdminDirectory.Users.list(optionalArgs);
```